# Can't delete li from to-do list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a to-do list application, and when the user clicks on a to-do that he/she has created, I want it to delete. But when I tested it out, it didn't delete.

```
$(document).ready(() => 
{
    $(".input input").on("keypress", check_todo);
    $(".output ul li").on("click", "li", delete_todo);
})

let check_todo = (e) => 
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13) 
    {
        if($(".input input").val() == "") 
        {
            no_todo();
        } 
        else 
        {
            add_todo();
        }
    }
}

let delete_todo = () => 
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

let add_todo = () => 
{
    let todo = $(".input input").val();

    $(".output ul").append(`<li>${todo}</li>`);
    $(".input input").val("");
}

let no_todo = () => 
{
    alert("Please add a new todo");
}
```

[See the HTML and a demo](http://codepen.io/thejseffect/pen/gLyBLQ?editors=0010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes.

**First,**

```
$(".output ul li").on("click", "li", delete_todo);
```

Should be...

```
$(".output").on("click", "li", delete_todo);
```

You need to bind the `click` event to `.output` rather than an `li`, because the `li` elements don't exist yet when that event is created. Also, the previous code was looking for a click on an `li` that was a child of `.output ul li`.

**Second,**

```
let delete_todo = () => {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Should be...

```
let delete_todo = (e) => {
    e.target.remove();
}
```

The context of `$(this)` would work in the click event itself, but not a function being called from it like this.

Comment: You should explain that the reason you can't use `$(this)` is because arrow functions keep the original value of `this`. It would work if he used traditional function syntax.