# Can't delete div from to-do list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a to-do list app, and in the app there is a div that wraps an input box (for the to-do item and so the user can edit the to-do) and a icon from font-awesome. When the user clicks on the icon, I want the **entire div** (which contains the to-do and the delete icon) to be deleted. But when tried to do that, it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Here's the JS Code

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".input input").on("keypress", check_todo);
    $(".fa-trash").on("click", ".todo_container", delete_todo);
})

// delete todo
let delete_todo = (e) => {
    e.target.remove();
}

// add todo
let add_todo = () => {
    let todo = $(".input input").val();

    $(".output").append(`
        <input type="text" placeholder="Edit To-do" value="${todo}"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        `);
    $(".input input").val("");
}

// check todo
let check_todo = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(".input input").val() == "") {
            no_todo();
        } else {
            add_todo();
        }
    }
}

// no todo
let no_todo = () => {
    alert("Please add a new todo");
}
```

[See the html and a demo](http://codepen.io/thejseffect/pen/gLyBLQ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't delete li from to-do list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292297/cant-delete-li-from-to-do-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should binding to `.out-put` container.

```
$(".output").on("click",".fa-trash" , delete_todo);
```

http://codepen.io/Vrety/pen/WoWmaE

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBoXZe

In your event listener, you need to swap `".todo_container"` and `".fa-trash"`.

```
 $(".todo_container").on("click",".fa-trash" , delete_todo);
```

This statement means, when a click event occurs and bubbles up to `.todo_container`, check if the clicked element is `.fa-trash`, if so call the function.

Then change your delete function

```
let delete_todo = (e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('.todo_container').remove()
}
```

This code means from the clicked icon, travel up the dom to find `.todo_container`, then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Good job with using the delegation in JQuery but while using it

```
$(".todo_container").on("click",".fa-trash" , delete_todo);
```

The base element `$(".todo_container")` needs to be static, You are deleting this also in the `delete_todo()` function.

Try using `$(".output")` instead and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

here is a working code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input input").on("keypress", check_todo);
  //$(".fa-trash").on("click", ".todo_container", delete_todo);
  $(".todo_container .fa-trash").on("click", delete_todo);
})

// delete todo
let delete_todo = function(e) {
  //e.target.remove();
  $(e.target).parent().remove();
}

// add todo
let add_todo = function() {
  let todo = $(".input input").val();

  //to do container element, the delete icon will added later
  var toDoContainer = $(`
        <div class="todo_container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Edit To-do" value="${todo}"></div>
        `);

  //create delete icon and set event listener
  var elem = $('<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>').on("click", delete_todo).appendTo(toDoContainer);



  $(".output").append(toDoContainer);
  $(".input input").val("");
}

// check todo
let check_todo = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if ($(".input input").val() == "") {
      no_todo();
    } else {
      add_todo();
    }
  }
}

// no todo
let no_todo = () => {
  alert("Please add a new todo");
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  src: url("assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular");
  font-weight: 400
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  src: url("assets/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold");
  font-weight: 600
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
*::selection {
  background-color: #ffffaa;
}
.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
}
.header input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: 400 1.8em Open Sans;
}
.to-do {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.input input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: 600 1em Open Sans;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
}
.output {
  margin: 10px;
}
.output input {
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: 600 1em Open Sans;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.output input:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.fa-trash {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-trash:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>To-do List</title>

  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <header class="header">
      <input type="text" name="edit_name" placeholder="Edit Name">
    </header>

    <section class="to-do">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="add_todo" placeholder="Click To Add A New To-do">
      </div>

      <div class="output">
        <div class="todo_container">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Edit To-do" value="Todo #1"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="todo_container">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Edit To-do" value="Todo #2"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>


  <!-- JQUERY -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5840114410.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did to fix.

Comment: It works on the to-do's that were already there but not on the new to-do's that you insert.

Comment: you have to set event listener to newly adding element

Comment: @SiddharthNand I updated my answer, now we can delete newly added element